# Pandas expanding count when column value changes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False]})

        A
0    True
1    True
2   False
3   False
4   False
5   False
6   False
7    True
8    True
9    True
10  False
```

I want to apply a count which expands using two criteria: each time column A changes value, or when succeeding rows are False. If succeeding rows are True the count should hold static. The desired output would be:

```
        A  B
0    True  1
1    True  1
2   False  2
3   False  3
4   False  4
5   False  5
6   False  6
7    True  7
8    True  7
9    True  7
10  False  8
```

I've faffed with a whole range of pandas functions and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

1st condition: *each time column A changes value*: `df.ne(df.shift()`

2nd condition: *when succeeding rows are False*: `df.eq(False)`

and do a `cumsum` over the boolean mask:

```
>>> (df.ne(df.shift()) | df.eq(False)).cumsum()
    A
0   1
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   7
9   7
10  8
```